# How to separate (x,y) to new coulmns x and y in R?

Tags: r

A dataset (CSV) file has a column latitudes and longitudes as (33, -118), (34, -119), (36, -120) etc. There are a million rows.

How can I seperate them, for instance how can I create two new columns with lat and long separate values. I know how to map using ggmap given lat and long in separate columns.

Thank you for your help

Comment: use `strsplit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myData)
myData[ , c('lat', 'lon') := tstrsplit(
  gsub('[()]', '', lat_lon_col), 
  split = ', ', 
  fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE
)]
```

Answer (score 2):

One more attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(col = c('(33, -118)', '(34, -119)', '(36, -120)'))

df %>% 
  mutate(col =col %>% str_sub(2,-2)) %>%  # remove ( and )
  separate(col, c('lat', 'lon'), convert=T) # separate


  lat lon
1  33 118
2  34 119
3  36 120
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the numbers from the column and create two new columns.

```
df[c('lat', 'lon')] <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$col, "-?\\d+", simplify = TRUE)
df

#         col lat  lon
#1 (33, -118)  33 -118
#2 (34, -119)  34 -119
#3 (36, -120)  36 -120
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col = c('(33, -118)', '(34, -119)', '(36, -120)'))
```